# Simulate button click in macOS SwiftUI?

Tags: macos, button, swiftui

I’ve built a simple macOS modal dialog in SwiftUI that takes some text from the user:

[image]

```swift
struct
OpenLocationView : View
{
    @State private var location: String = ""

    var body: some View
    {
        VStack
        {
            HStack
            {
                Text("Location:")
                TextField("https://", text: $location) { self.openLocation() }
            }

            HStack
            {
                Spacer()
                Button("Cancel") { self.dismiss() }
                Button("Open") { self.simulateClick() }
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(minWidth: 500.0)
    }
}
```

If the user presses enter or return, I’d like to briefly simulate a click on the default button before dismissing the dialog. How would I do this in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 2):

Actually you've almost done it, see comments inline

```swift
...
    HStack
    {
        Text("Location:")
        TextField("https://", text: $location) { 
           // this is onCommit: called on Return or Enter
           self.open() 
        }
    }

    HStack
    {
        Spacer()
        Button("Cancel") { self.dismiss() }
        Button("Open") { self.open() }
    }

...

func open() {
    self.openLocation() 
    self.dismiss()
}
```

Comment: Hmm, you don't seem to show how to simulate the button click. What I mean by that is I want the Open button to briefly flash blue before dismissing the dialog.

Comment: @Rick see ButtonStyle protocol

Comment: @user3441734 Seems like you've got a great answer there! If you elaborate with some example code in your own answer to this question, it'll probably get accepted!